# CDT An internal error occurred during: "Setting up indexer"

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, indexer

I use Eclipse with CDT to build C++ code.
After loading my workspace I get the following message:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Setting up indexer".
```

Here is the log:

```
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2012-10-30 16:46:09.940
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Setting up indexer".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.pdom.db.Database.getChunk(Database.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.pdom.db.Database.getRecPtr(Database.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.pdom.dom.PDOMLinkage.getLinkageID(PDOMLinkage.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.pdom.PDOM.readLinkages(PDOM.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.pdom.PDOM.loadDatabase(PDOM.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.pdom.PDOM.<init>(PDOM.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.pdom.WritablePDOM.<init>(WritablePDOM.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.pdom.WritablePDOM.<init>(WritablePDOM.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.pdom.PDOMManager.getOrCreatePDOM(PDOMManager.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.pdom.PDOMManager.createIndexer(PDOMManager.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.pdom.PDOMSetupJob.run(PDOMSetupJob.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

How can I fix/reset this ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Deleting the *.pdom files from .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.core/ solved the problem

Comment: That worked for me. I was able to delete the .pdom for the 1 project that was giving me trouble.

Comment: Should be pointed out that this path is inside the current Eclipse workspace root folder